# Добавление поля

Tags: jquery, html

Пробую сделать так, что при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить поле", с помощью jQuery, появлялся перед закрывающим тегом `</ul>` вот такой кусок кода:

```
<li>
<input type="text">
<button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
</li>
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#add').click(function(){
            $('<li><input><button>+</button></li>').insertBefore('</ul>');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Поля для редактирования</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="surname">Фамилия:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="surname">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Имя:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="">Отчество:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="">Должность:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="company">Название компании:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="company">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="address">Адрес:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="address">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="phone">Телефон:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="icq">ICQ:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="icq">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="skype">Skype:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="skype">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" title="Добавить поле" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Добавить поле</a>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-success">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Слегка не по теме, просто интересно: а почему бы не использовать `$('ul').append(...)` вместо `....insertBefore('</ul>')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').click(function(){
    $('<li><input><button>+</button></li>').insertBefore('</ul>');
  });
});
```

Comment: и что работает так? удивительно ))

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').click(function(){
     $('ul').append('<li><input type="text"/><button class="btn btn-primary">+</button></li>')
  });
});
```

Классы и атрибуты лучше сразу указать. И добавляем через $('ul').append() (плюс [@Crasher](/users/3358/crasher)).

Неужели у вас вот эта конструкция `$('</ul>')` хоть что-то выбирала (пустой массив не считается) :)?

Comment: @iKuzko, функции `$('</ul>')` не было, там было `$(...).insertBefore('</ul>')`, а функция `.insertBefore()`, требует селектор, эллемент, обьект или *строчку*.

Comment: У меня этот кусок кода, который Вы написали, не хочет работать!